# Склонение фамилии Саладуха

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Ольга Саладуха - это украинская спортсменка, прыгунья тройным прыжком. Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли склонять её фамилию? Например, так:

На момент публикации интервью Саладухе было 32 года.

Answer (score 4):

> Славянские фамилии, оканчивающиеся на ударный и безударный -а,
>   склоняются. Вопреки распространенному заблуждению, склоняются в том
>   числе и фамилии, совпадающие с нарицательными существительными.
>
> Примеры: ***тетрадь Ирины Грозы***, диплом выдан Николаю Мухе, лекция Елены
>   Кара-Мурзы, роли Игоря Кваши.

[**источник**](http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_8_familii/)

Верно: ***На момент публикации интервью Саладухе было 32 года.***

Ещё одно подробное изложение темы:

> Нестандартные женские фамилии с окончанием на звук -а (-я), такие как
>   Зоя, Зима, рекомендуется склонять по правилам множественного числа для
>   всех падежей формы, совпадающей с первоначальной формой данной
>   фамилии.
>
> Например: Ирине Ивановне Зиме, Светлану Сергеевну Зою и т. д. А для
>   множественного числа — первостепенной формы Зоя, Зима, во всех
>   падежах.   Наиболее сложное склонение в таких фамилиях представляют
>   собой женские фамилии с окончанием на звук -а. Важно понимать, следует
>   ли окончание -а после гласной или же после согласной, а также падает
>   ли на эту гласную ударение и (в определенных конкретных случаях) какое
>   происхождение имеет фамилия. Для склонения подобных женских фамилий,
>   целесообразно обратиться к справочнику склонения имен и фамилий.
>
> Все женские фамилии, имеющие окончание на звук -а, перед которым стоят
>   гласные (чаще всего у или и), несклоняемы: Валуа, Горуа, Белакруа,
>   Доравиа, Иэриа, Эредиа, Булиа.
>
> Все женские фамилии, имеющие окончание на неударный звук - а стоящий
>   после согласных, склоняются по правилам первого склонения: Дибера —
>   Диберы, Дибере, Диберу, Диберой, Сенека — Сенеки и т.п.; таким же
>   образом склоняются Пафка, Стиноза, Сметана, Сетрарка, Буросава,
>   Злинка, Дейнека, Гулыга, Овеша, Согнибеда, Окуржава и др. Все подобные
>   женские фамилии, независимо от своего происхождения, являются
>   морфологически делимыми в русском языке, т. е. в них явно выделяется
>   окончание на звук -а.
>
> Среди женских фамилий с ударным -а, стоящим после согласных, есть как
>   морфологически делимые, то есть склоняемые, так и не делимые, то есть
>   не склоняемые.
>
> Не склоняются женские фамилии французского происхождения: Люма, Гома,
>   Рега, Люка, Гамарра, Петипа и др.
>
> ***Женские фамилии славянского происхождения и из восточных языков склоняются по правилам первого склонения, т. е. в них исчезает ударное
>   окончание - а: Ритта — Ритты, Ритте, Ритту, Риттой; к ним относятся:
>   Сковорода, так же Кочерга, так же Кваша, так же Цабаса, так же Харза и
>   др.*** Для склонения подобных женских фамилий, целесообразно
>   обратиться к справочнику склонения имен и фамилий.

[**источник**](http://vsefamilii.ru/vsefamilii-sklonjenfam.html)

Answer (score 2):

Да, фамилия Саладуха склоняется – как мужская, так и женская.